# need help in formatting data using awk using ARGV[1], ARGV[2]

Tags: text-processing, awk

Need help in formatting data using `awk` using `ARGV[1]`, `ARGV[2]`
join data using `awk` with `ARGV`.

file1

```
sg_metro-ir
sg_metro-nonir
sg_optimized
sh_server1
sh_server2
sh_server3
sh_server4
```

file2

```
vh_server1 ih_server1 sh_server1 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
vh_server2 ih_server2 sh_server2 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
vh_server3 ih_server3 sh_server3 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
vh_server4 ih_server4 sh_server4 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
```

output

```
sg_metro-ir  NOTFOUND
sg_metro-nonir NOTFOUND
sg_optimized NOTFOUND
sh_server1 vh_server1 ih_server1 sh_server1 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
sh_server2 vh_server2 ih_server2 sh_server2 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server3 vh_server3 ih_server3 sh_server3 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server4  vh_server4 ih_server4 sh_server4 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
```

I was trying to use below logic.

```
VMAX_ALL_JOIN () {
awk  '{
  if (FILENAME==ARGV[0]) {a=$1;$1!="";sg_list[a]=$1} 
  if (FILENAME==ARGV[2] && $1!="") {print VAR_ARRAY_NAME, VAR_ARRAY_SNO, match(sg_list[$1],/[^ ]/) ? $0 : "NO_VIEW",   $0,sg_list[$1]}

}
' file1 file2 
}
VMAX_ALL_JOIN
```

I even tried this.

```
awk -F' ' -v OFS=' ' ' FNR==NR {f1[$1];next}; { if ($3 in f1) {print f1[$1], $0} else {print f1[$1], VIEW_NOT_FOUND} }' file1 file2
```

it is printing only values found in file2 but I wanted to make if something not found, print with conditidon doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you please update your question? Please post the script or command you use to achieve the desired output, and an example of the actual output. Please use the curly brackets { } around your code / output snippets so the formatting is readable. Please don't answer in a comment - when you update the question all the necessary info is readily available for anyone that wants to pitch in.

Comment: I edited the formatting with the curly brackets. The edit will come visible once a senior member of the community approves it.

Comment: Your script uses `FILENAME==ARGV[0]` instead of `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` so it's comparing the current file name with the path to the awk interpreter. What are `VAR_ARRAY_NAME`, `VAR_ARRAY_SNO`, and `VIEW_NOT_FOUND` in your scripts? If the answer is shell variables then see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: You should really think through what `{a=$1;$1!="";sg_list[a]=$1}` does in your first script. `a=$1` sets `a` to the value of `$1`. Then `$1!=""` tests if `$1` is not equal to `""` but does nothing with the result of that comparison. Then `sg_list[a]=$1` stores the value of `$1` in an array `sg_list` indexed by that same value of `$1` (as stored in `a` at your first step). Obviously that makes no sense. There's no magic or mystery in awk, you simply write the code just like you would in C or any other Algol-based language, you just have to think about what each statement you write does.

Comment: In `-F' ' -v OFS=' '` you're setting `FS` and `OFS` to single blank chars. What are the default values for `FS` and `OFS`? Single blank chars. So those assignments are doing absolutely nothing except taking up CPU cycles. What were you hoping they would do? Don't write code if you don''t have a purpose in mind for it.

Comment: I forgot to remove VAR_ARRAY_NAME, VAR_ARRAY_SNO.. I tried to get rid of unwanted data in question but forgot to remove when I paste here. those are external variables which I am going to introduce. aslo thanks for for unwanted code regarding "-F' ' -v OFS=' '"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process the files the other way around, i.e. first read and process file2 then file1:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { f2[$3]=$0; next };
{ print $0, ($1 in f2)? f2[$1]: "VIEW_NOT_FOUND" }' file2 file1
```

If `file2` could be empty, you can't rely on `FNR!=NR` for the second file (`file1`) though. Instead, you can do:

```
awk '! file2_processed { f2[$3]=$0; next };
     { print $0, ($1 in f2) ? f2[$1]: "VIEW_NOT_FOUND" }
    ' file2 file2_processed=1 file1
```

Which in general is a safer trick than relying on `FNR==NR` to know which file you're processing (and less expensive than your `FILENAME == ARGV[0]` which in the general case you should write as `FILENAME == ARGV[1] ""` to force string comparison since both are of "type" numeric-string if the file name is a number; and note the first arg is in `ARGV[1]`, not `ARGV[0]` which contains the name of the awk script). See also the `ARGIND` of GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 { f2[$3]=$0; next };
     { print $0, ($1 in f2) ? f2[$1]: "VIEW_NOT_FOUND" }
    ' file2 file1
```

---

With the way that you are processing the files (file1 first against the file2), you might want to do something like below:

```
awk '! file1_processed { f1[$0]; next };
     ($3 in f1){ print $3, $0; delete f1[$3] }
END{ for(x in f1) print x, "VIEW_NOT_FOUND" }' file1 file1_processed=1 file2
```

This first printing the matched lines and delete the matched keys from the associated array `f1`, then print the unmatched ones later in the output as following:

```
sh_server1 vh_server1 ih_server1 sh_server1 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
sh_server2 vh_server2 ih_server2 sh_server2 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server3 vh_server3 ih_server3 sh_server3 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server4 vh_server4 ih_server4 sh_server4 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
sg_metro-ir VIEW_NOT_FOUND
sg_metro-nonir VIEW_NOT_FOUND
sg_optimized VIEW_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in `cat file1`; do j=$(grep -i "$i"   file2); if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then  echo -e "$i Notfound"; else echo -e "$i $j"; fi; done
```

output

```
sg_metro-ir Notfound
sg_metro-nonir Notfound
sg_optimized Notfound
sh_server1 vh_server1 ih_server1 sh_server1 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
sh_server2 vh_server2 ih_server2 sh_server2 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server3 vh_server3 ih_server3 sh_server3 E1-2_D1-4_P05_pg2
sh_server4 vh_server4 ih_server4 sh_server4 E1-2_D1-4_P04_pg1
```